# Missing layout,system and template items under sitecore node

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-rocks

As you can see in two images ! I'm missing layout,system and template. when I open it with sitecore rocks it says "Modified- must be serialized."
I'm wondering if anyone had this issue before and how you fixed it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you have the same problem i had at some point in a new installation:

1. Go to the `View` tab in the Content Editor
2. If the Option `Hidden Items` is not checked, check it

This should work now. These root items are marked as hidden.

Comment: thanks a lot! it sounds simple answer but if you don't know you'll end up spending so much time

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved my day.